# The Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: calculus

Im struggling to understand how some definitions are valid, for instance, consider this:

Let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing function on $[a,b]$ (since $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$ are finite, it follows that $\alpha$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, i will not prove the finiteness). Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, we write:

$\Delta{\alpha_i}$ = $\alpha(x_i)$ - $\alpha(x_{i-1})$, it is clear that $\Delta{\alpha_i} \geq 0$

Now for any real function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ we put

$M_i = \sup f(x)$ whenever $(x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i)$ and $m_i= \inf f(x)$ whenever $(x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i)$, furthermore,

$U(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i}{\Delta \alpha_i}$ aswell as $L(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{m_i}{\Delta \alpha_i}$

My question is, since $\alpha$ is a monotone function, it may have discontinuities, what kind of discontinuities are we talking about? Jump points? Most importantly, what if we consider a partition $P$, and then for some $1 \le k \le n$ we have that $\Delta{\alpha_k}$ = $\alpha(x_k)$ - $\alpha(x_{k-1})$ but $\alpha$ is not continuous at $x_k$? Then $\Delta{\alpha_k}$ wont even be defined, so in my opinion we must assume that $\alpha$ is a continuous function, is this wrong?

Comment: Why would the fact that $\alpha$ isn't continuous at $x_k$ imply that $\Delta\alpha_k$ is undefined?

Comment: To answer one of your questions: yes, jumps. A monotonic function can have only jump discontinuities.

Comment: So at a jump point $x_k$ of $\alpha$, what value does $\alpha(x_k)$ attend?

Comment: You said at the beginning, "let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing **function** on $[a,b]$..."  This means it assigns a value to every point in $[a,b]$, including $x_k$.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, all discontinuities of a monotone function are jump discontinuities.  The precise statement is as follows.  A *jump function* for a set $D \subseteq [a,b]$ is a function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ such that $\sum_{x \in D} f_+(x) - f_-(x) = f(b) - f(a)$ where $f_+$ is the right limit and $f_-$ is the left limit of $f$.  It is not too hard to prove that every monotone function is the sum of a continuous function and a jump function.

Comment: @PaulSiegel , if $x_k$ is a jump point of $\alpha$ what value do we assign $\alpha(x_k)$, do we assign the value $\alpha_{+}(x_k)$ or $\alpha_{-}(x_k)$. Obviously these are two different values since we consider a jump point? Can someone clarify this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the left limit or the right limit!  Consider the function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$, and $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.  This is a perfectly good monotone function.

Comment: @PaulSiegel. Oh, i get it. Could you give me one example of a monotonically increasing function $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$ and a real and bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that

$\inf U(P,f,\alpha) \not= \sup L(P,f,\alpha)$ where inf and sup are taken over all partitions $P$. That is, a function $f$ such that $f \notin \Re(\alpha)$

Comment: Well if $\alpha(x) = x$ then you recover the ordinary Riemann integral, so with that choice of $\alpha$ you can take $f$ to be any function which is not Riemann-integrable (e.g. the characteristic function of the rationals).

Answer (score 0):

For Riemann stieltjes integrability of $f$ with respecr $\alpha $ it is nessessery that $f$ and $\alpha $ have no common one sided discontinuity. Also
sets of measure zero are important in this topic.